# doxygen having issue with markdown images

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I tried most simple markdown image format like this

```
![from web](http://qassociates.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/apple_logo2.jpg)

![from system](file:///home/xyz.jpg)
```

Initially I tried this on retext and exported as a pdf and it is showing both images perfectly
But when tried the same syntax for my markdown text file which is further I am creating as a pdf using doxygen its not showing any images ,any idea ?? Am I missing something ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I tried this [link](http://sourceforge.net/p/doxygen/mailman/message/30683537/) and it is working .

this maybe the problem with doxygen, I guess to detect markdown images.

so I tried this latex commands

```
@image latex home/picture.png
```

and besides this we can pass any latex (latex image commands also ) command to doxygen by using like this in text file

```
\latexonly

latex command here

\endlatexonly
```